# Search multiple custom post types with tags

Tags: search

I have blog with some post and pages and a forum, i need a search such that it need to search tags in post and pages and not in forum (bbpress)

```
if ($query->is_search()) {
    $postType = array();
    $tagPostType = array();
    $tags = array();
    if (isset($_GET['taglist']) && is_array($_GET['taglist'])) {
        $tagPostType = array('page','post');
        $postType = array_merge($postType, $tagPostType);
        $tags = $_GET['taglist'];
     } else {
         $postType =  array('forum','topic','reply','page','post');
     }
     if(isset($_GET['forums'])) {
         $tags = '';
         $postType = array_merge($tagPostType, array('forum','topic','reply'));
     }
     print_R($postType);
     $query->set('tag_slug__in', $tags);
     $query->set('post_type', $postType);
    return $query;
}
```

i need to search tags in post/pages and not in forums.

Comment: Welcome at WPSE. Have you already had a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) WordPress unfortunately doesn't make this possible out of the box. You'd either need a plugin (which would be off topic to ask for at WPSE) or code it yourself. Then you'd need to add some research and code to your question. Please have a look at the links above.

Comment: You want to search posts, pages, and forums in general, but only search tags for posts and pages?

Comment: Got the answer i made functions usng the filters
add_filter('posts_join', 'forum_search_join');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filters to create custom search querys

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'forum_search_join')
add_filter('posts_where', 'forum_search_where');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join